# Hide google map markers until activated by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Google map set up which filters markers depending on their category. However they are currently visible when you first land on the page. Once you have triggered all the checkbox filters they are then hidden. However I would like the markers to be hidden when you first land on the page and are only visible when triggered by the checkbox filter.

Here is my code:

```
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Apple', 51.514227, -0.142056, 'shopping'],
    ['1', 'Title 1', 51.512424, -0.147783, 'hotels'],
    ['2', 'Title 2', 51.512164, -0.144521, 'culture'],
    ['3', 'Title 3', 51.511697, -0.144113, 'foodanddrink'],
    ['4', 'Title 4', 51.511817, -0.143566, 'shopping']
];

mp = [
    ['0', 51.512187, -0.144769, 'shopping']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5117389, -0.1452168);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5117389, -0.1452168),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
        addMp(mp[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Add Main Point Marker
 */
function addMp(marker) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[1], marker[2]);
    var content = marker[1];

    var icon = {
        url: "../images/mp-marker.svg",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60), 
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30) 
    };

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        zIndex: 9999,
    }); 
}


/**
 * Function to add markers to map
 */
function addMarker(marker) {
    var tip = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    var icon = {
        url: "../images/map-marker.svg",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), 
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15) 
    };

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        tip: tip,
        map: map,
        icon: icon
    }); 

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
        return function() {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            //map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            //map.setZoom(17);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}


var tipovi = document.getElementsByClassName('chk-btn').value;

var selectAllChecked = function() {
    var checkedPlace = [] 
    var allCheckedElem = document.getElementsByName('filter');
    for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedElem.length; i++) {
        if (allCheckedElem[i].checked == true) {
            checkedPlace.push(allCheckedElem[i].value)//creating array of checked items
        }
    }
    filterChecker(checkedPlace) //passing to function for updating markers
}

var filterChecker = function(tip) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {

        marker = gmarkers1[i];

        if (in_array(this.marker.tip, tip) != -1) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
         marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
// Init map
initialize();

function in_array(needle, haystack) {
    var found = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
        found++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="map-nav">
          <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
            <label class="switch">
              <span>Shopping</span>
              <input id="shopping-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="shopping" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
              <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
            <label class="switch">
              <span>Food and drink</span>
              <input id="food-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="foodanddrink" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
              <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
            <label class="switch">
              <span>Hotels</span>
              <input id="hotels-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="hotels" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
              <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
            <label class="switch">
              <span>Culture</span>
              <input id="culture-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="culture" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
              <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your markers to show until the check box is checked, don't add them to the map until the check box is checked.

When you create the marker, don't set the `map` property.

```
function addMarker(marker) {
  // snip (start of function)

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        tip: tip,
        icon: icon
    }); 
   // rest of function
```

When the filter function shows the marker, add it to or remove it from the map:

```
var filterChecker = function(tip) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        if (in_array(this.marker.tip, tip) != -1) {
          marker.setMap(map);
        } else {
          marker.setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d6e9rfb0/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', 'Apple', 51.514227, -0.142056, 'shopping'],
  ['1', 'Title 1', 51.512424, -0.147783, 'hotels'],
  ['2', 'Title 2', 51.512164, -0.144521, 'culture'],
  ['3', 'Title 3', 51.511697, -0.144113, 'foodanddrink'],
  ['4', 'Title 4', 51.511817, -0.143566, 'shopping']
];

mp = [
  ['0', 51.512187, -0.144769, 'shopping']
];


/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5117389, -0.1452168);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5117389, -0.1452168),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
    addMp(mp[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * Add Main Point Marker
 */
function addMp(marker) {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[1], marker[2]);
  var content = marker[1];

  var icon = {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30)
  };

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    zIndex: 9999,
  });
}


/**
 * Function to add markers to map
 */
function addMarker(marker) {
  var tip = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[1];

  var icon = {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
  };

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    tip: tip,
    //        map: map,
    icon: icon
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      //map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      //map.setZoom(17);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}


var tipovi = document.getElementsByClassName('chk-btn').value;

var selectAllChecked = function() {
  var checkedPlace = []
  var allCheckedElem = document.getElementsByName('filter');
  for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedElem.length; i++) {
    if (allCheckedElem[i].checked == true) {
      checkedPlace.push(allCheckedElem[i].value) //creating array of checked items
    }
  }
  filterChecker(checkedPlace) //passing to function for updating markers
}

var filterChecker = function(tip) {
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    if (in_array(this.marker.tip, tip) != -1) {
      marker.setMap(map);
    } else {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
// Init map
initialize();

function in_array(needle, haystack) {
  var found = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    found++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map-canvas {
  height: 70%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="map-nav">
  <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
    <label class="switch">
      <span>Shopping</span>
      <input id="shopping-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="shopping" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
      <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
    <label class="switch">
      <span>Food and drink</span>
      <input id="food-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="foodanddrink" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
      <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
    <label class="switch">
      <span>Hotels</span>
      <input id="hotels-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="hotels" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
      <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="map-nav__item js-fade-in-up">
    <label class="switch">
      <span>Culture</span>
      <input id="culture-item" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="culture" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
      <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```